# Filter pandas dataframe based on threshold value and including the row afterwards

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with several columns - for simplicity, column A is a column of integers that are strictly increasing.

```
A    B    ...
103
222
383
432
799
1089
...
```

I would like to filter the dataframe based on a threshold value for column A, e.g. 750. I can do something like `df[df['A'] < 750]` to achieve this. This results in:

```
A    B    ...
103
222
383
432
...
```

However, I would like to include the value directly after this threshold value as well - e.g. the resulting dataframe also should contain the 799 row.

```
A    B    ...
103
222
383
432
799
...
```

A clunky way to do this is just to `pd.concat` these two dataframes `df[df['A'] < 750]` and `df[df['A'] >= 750].iloc[0]` together - it is essentially the original filter plus the single row directly after 750, which is 799, hence the `iloc[0]`. Is there some sort of built in method achieve this result, without having to do this manual concat?

Comment: Is `A` supposed to contain numbers in increasing order?

Comment: yes - have corrected the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) assuming the dataframe is sorted by `A` values. And this should be very fast.

By default the side is `left` for searchsorted and because you first want to filter < 750 first and then include the next higher element to 750 then side=left should be good.

```
df.loc[:df['A'].searchsorted(750)]
```

Output (with made up 'B' values):

```
      A     B
0   103     1
1   222     2
2   383     3
3   432     4
4   799     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the first true value using `idxmax` where `df['A']` is greater than 750.

Note that `loc` will create a slice of the original frame so if you want to preform other operations on the slice you may want to make a `.copy()`

```
df.loc[:df['A'].gt(750).idxmax()]

     A
0  103
1  222
2  383
3  432
4  799
```

Or if you want to use less than instead use `idxmin` which will find the index of the first false value as `False == 0`

```
df.loc[:df['A'].lt(750).idxmin()]
```